# Cannot install Ubuntu on Dell computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7, dell

I have a Dell computer with Windows 7 pre-installed. I am trying to install Ubuntu on it as Dual Boot, but unsuccessfully. I have created a USB boot with latest Ubuntu image on it. I have also followed the steps [here on dell.com](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN151792/en) and "shrink volume".

On boot, I press <kbd>F12</kbd> and select the USB device to boot from. I am then presented with a menu with different options:

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- Memory test 
  etc.

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Memory test, the test starts running. However, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the other menu items (either trying or installing Ubuntu), the computer reboots and goes back into Windows. I have also tried at this step to boot into USB again. But all I get is the same menu, and selecting any option just reboots the computer. I feel like I'm stuck in a loop of some sort.

EDIT:

At first I used pendrivelinux to create the bootable usb stick as per [this guide on ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

I then use Linux Live to create the usb stick instead. Using this method, I was able to get to Install prompt, where it asks me whether I want to **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**. If I select this, the system reboots again and then I am back to square one. A little further than before, but still no go.

I have never had such a hard time installing Ubuntu before...

Comment: have u tried checking the usb drive for defects

Comment: what kind of defect? how could I check that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem appears to be abandoned. More information is required to solve it but it's very unlikely now OP still stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem I'm having has to do with the number of partitions.

When I go to **Disk Management**, there are 4 partitions - OEM partition, Recovery (primary), System (primary) and Win 7 (primary). I thought that the OEM one would not count towards the 4 primary partitions limit. But apparently it does.

I could not delete any of these partitions except for the Recovery one, so that's what I ended up doing.

EDIT: apparently the OEM partition doesn't count as primary, however Ubuntu requires 2 primary partitions by itself, which is why it refused to go through with the installation. At any rate, it would have been nice to see a notice about insufficient primary partitions or something, instead of just rebooting the system.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't need 2 primary partitions to get installed, on the contrary it needs _zero_ primary partition. And your info is wrong, Recovery OEM partition is counted.

Comment: And it's not clear if your problem is solved! Did you actually get Ubuntu installed ?